# Is there a scoping variable for Rally like __PROJECT_SCOPING__ but for releases?

Tags: rally

I'm trying to make a Release Summary Rally App that responds to the pages Release Scoping on the page instead of having it's own release "picker".

I'm looking to replace

```
        {
            key: "release",
            type: "release",
            fetch: "Notes",
            query: new rally.sdk.util.Query("ObjectID = " + rally.sdk.util.Ref.getOidFromRef(releaseDropdown.getSelectedItem()))
        }
```

with something like this:

```
        {
            key: "release",
            type: "release",
            fetch: "Notes",
            query: new rally.sdk.util.Query("ObjectID = " + __RELEASE_SCOPING__)
        }
```

But I can't find any evidence of such a field.

How is the release status on the page communicated to the apps on the page? How can I get a handle on what release is currently being displayed so I can manipulate my app to respond to that information?

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible.  Check out this doc:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps-timebox-filtered-dashboards

Your code would then probably look something like this:

```
var panelContext = rally.sdk.util.Context.getPanelContext();
if(panelContext.timeboxFilter && panelContext.timeboxFilter.release) {
    var release = panelContext.timeboxFilter.release; //the release object
    var releaseQuery = panelContext.timeboxFilter.query; //a query to find all "like" releases in the current project scope

    var queryObj = {
        key: "release",
        type: "release",
        fetch: "Notes",
        query: new rally.sdk.util.Query("ObjectID = " + release.ObjectID)
    }
    //do the query
    //rallyDataSource.findAll(queryObj...)
}
```